# No entiendo porque se cambia toda la estructura

Tags: javascript

No entiendo porque al volver a lo que vendria siendo el wrapper (sección principal) se cambia toda la estructura, el css se ve super afectado, intente utilizando la clase visibility, display block o incluso con una simple etiqueta a. No entiendo cual es el error de esta pagina ya que intente con todo y no funciona. Adjunto pruebas:[image: ANTES]

[image: despues]

```
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper")
    const botones = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
    const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel")
    const slides = carousel.querySelectorAll(".slide")
    const volver = document.getElementById('volver')

    for(let i = 0; i < botones.length; i++){
    
    botones[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        const loader = document.getElementById("loader")
        loader.style.display = "block"
        wrapper.style.display = "none"


        setTimeout(function(){
            loader.style.display = "none"
            carousel.style.display = "block"
        },3000)
    })
}

    volver.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // const loader = document.getElementById('loader')
    // loader.style.display = 'block'
    carousel.style.display = 'none'
    wrapper.style.display =  'block'

    // setTimeout(function(){
    //     loader.style.display = 'none'
    //     wrapper.style.display = 'block'
    // },3000)
})
```

Comment: Procura mostrar un [repro]. Como tu código es HTML+CSS+JS, puedes agregar un snippet en la pregunta (con el botón que indica `<>`) para que tu código pueda ser ejecutado allí mismo.